# How does this python package execute download.sh file when pip install?

Tags: python, pip

https://github.com/RR2DO2/maxminddb-geolite2

There is download.sh file, but what executes it, when and how?

There is no 'execute download.sh' kind of code anywhere inside the library.

What triggers download.sh?

pip install automatically finds and recognizes and executes it? how? where is the setting? is it a default behavior of pip install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing triggers `download.sh`. I think you should execute this bash script manually in order to download database file if you want to work with it.

Pip doesn't execute it.

Comment: But without executing download.sh on my side, I just could use `from geolite2 import geolite2` and can just use it. Even the db was downloaded in my Lib\site-packages\_maxminddb_geolite2 (download.sh downloads the db)

Comment: @Arbitrary I hope you can. I just don't know this library and its specifications. Maybe it can work with another db's and db in download.sh just an example. I only know it isn't executed by pip :)

Comment: I made a virtualenv and `pip install maxminddb-geolite2` and I didn't do anything more but there was already the db file in `Lib\site-packages\_maxminddb_geolite2`...I didn't import anything in code..Doesn't that mean `pip install` download it?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Just github repo didn't include the db but actual pypi.org package included the db. Sorry.